# How to validate my radio button fields using magento?

Tags: magento-1.8, php

I have created the form but i could validate my radio button fields.
When I click on the submit it is not showing any alert symbol.

When no radio button is selected it has to show as in the image for radio button.
please anyone help me.

My form

```
  <form action="<?php echo $this->getFormAction(); ?>" id="bookingtest" method="post">
<div class="fieldset">
    <ul class="form-list">
        <li class="fields">
        <div class="field">
            <label for="testname" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Test Name') ?> </label>
                <div class="input-box">
                    <input type="text" id="testname" name="testname" value="<?php echo $_GET['name']?>" class="input-text required-entry" title="<?php echo $this->__('Test Name') ?>" />
                </div>
            </div>  

            <div class="field"> 

            <label for="city" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('City') ?> </label>
                <div class="input-box">
                        <input type="text" id="city" name="city" value="<?php echo $_GET['city']?>" class="input-text required-entry" title="<?php echo $this->__('City') ?>" />
                </div>
        </div>
        </li>
        <li>

            <label for="location" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Location') ?> </label>
                <div class="input-box">
                        <input type="text" id="location" name="location" value="<?php echo $_GET['location']?>" class="input-text required-entry" title="<?php echo $this->__('Location') ?>" />
                </div>

        </li>
        <li class="fields">
        <div class="field">
            <label for="cname" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Name') ?> </label>
                <div class="input-box">
                        <input type="text" id="cname" name="cname" value="" class="input-text required-entry" title="<?php echo $this->__('Name') ?>" />
                </div>
            </div>
        <div class="field">
         <label for="email" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Email Address') ?></label>
                <div class="input-box">
                    <input type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getUsername()) ?>" id="email" class="input-text required-entry validate-email" title="<?php echo $this->__('Email Address') ?>" />
                </div>
        </div>
        </li>
        <li>

            <label for="mobile" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Mobile Number') ?> </label>
                        <div class="input-box">
                            <input type="text" id="mobile" name="mobile" value="" class="input-text required-entry validate-mobileno" title="<?php echo $this->__('Mobile Number') ?>" />
                        </div>
         </li>
          <li>
          <label class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Sample Collection') ?> </label></li>
          <li>
                <div class="radio_button">
                <input type="radio" name="radio" class="input-text required-entry validate-select" value="I will visit Lab"> I will visit Lab
                </div>
                <div>
                <input type="radio" name="radio" class="input-text required-entry validate-select" value="Visit me at home/office +Rs50.00" > Visit me at home/office +Rs50.00
                </div>
         </li>
         <li>
                <label for="testschedule" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Test Schedule') ?> </label>
                    <div class="input-box">
                        <input type="text" id="testschedule" name="testschedule" value="" class="input-text required-entry" title="<?php echo $this->__('Test Schedule') ?>" style="width: 150px;" />
                        <img style="" title="Select Date" id="date_select_trig" alt="" src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl("images/calendar.gif");?> "/>
                        <select name="date_time" id="date_time" class="input-text required-entry validate-select" style="width: 50px;" />
                                    <option value=""><?php echo $this->__('--')?></option>
                                    <option value="1"><?php echo $this->__('1')?></option>
                                    <option value="2"><?php echo $this->__('2')?></option>
                                    <option value="3"><?php echo $this->__('3')?></option>
                                    <option value="4"><?php echo $this->__('4')?></option>
                                    <option value="5"><?php echo $this->__('5')?></option>
                                    <option value="6"><?php echo $this->__('6')?></option>
                                    <option value="7"><?php echo $this->__('7')?></option>
                                    <option value="8"><?php echo $this->__('8')?></option>
                                    <option value="9"><?php echo $this->__('9')?></option>
                                    <option value="10"><?php echo $this->__('10')?></option>
                                    <option value="11"><?php echo $this->__('11')?></option>
                                    <option value="12"><?php echo $this->__('12')?></option>
                            </select>
                            <b>:</b>


                    </div>
        </li>

    </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="button">
<p class="required"><?php echo $this->__('* Required Fields') ?></p>
    <button id= "submit"  type="submit" class="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Book Test') ?>" name="send" id="send2"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Book Test') ?></span></span></button>
</div>


 </form>

  <script src="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl('js')."calendar/calendar.js" ?>" type="text/javascript"></script>

   <script src="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl('js')."calendar/calendar-setup.js" ?>" type="text/javascript"></script>

   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl('js') ?>calendar/calendar-win2k-1.css"  />
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('core/html_calendar')->setTemplate('page/js/calendar.phtml')->toHtml();?>

  <script type="text/javascript">

    if(Validation) {
     Validation.addAllThese([
['validate-mobileno','Enter correct mobile number (Eg:9986858483)',
   function(v){
    //var timePat ="^((\+){0,1}91(\s){0,1}(\-){0,1}(\s){0,1}){0,1}9[0-9](\s){0,1}(\-){0,1}(\s){0,1}[1-9]{1}[0-9]{7}$";

var timePat ="^{0,1}9[0-9](\s){0,1}(\-){0,1}(\s){0,1}[1-9]{1}[0-9]{7}$";
// var matchArray = v.match(timePat);
if(v.length > 0){
if(v.length !=10){
    return false;
   }else if(v[0]!=9 && v[0]!=8 && v[0]!=7){

    return false;
   }


return true;

}else {
return false;
}

}
   ]])
  };
   var dataForm = new VarienForm('bookingtest', true); 
 </script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
   // <![CDATA[
 Calendar.setup({
 inputField : 'testschedule',
   ifFormat : '%d-%b-%Y',
showsTime: false,
 button : 'date_select_trig',
 singleClick : true,
 });
   // ]]>
</script>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<li>
          <label class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Sample Collection') ?> </label></li>
          <li>
                <div class="radio_button">
                <input type="radio" name="radio" class="input-radio validate-one-required-by-name" value="I will visit Lab"> I will visit Lab
                </div>
                <div>
                <input type="radio" name="radio" class="input-radio  validate-one-required-by-name" value="Visit me at home/office +Rs50.00" > Visit me at home/office +Rs50.00
                </div>
         </li>
```

for html

```
    <div class="input-box">
  <div style="float:left">
                            <input type="text" id="testschedule" name="testschedule" value="" class="input-text required-entry validation-failed" title="Test Schedule" style="width: 150px;"><div style="" id="advice-required-entry-testschedule" class="validation-advice">This is a required field.</div></div><div style="float:left">
                            <img style="" title="Select Date" id="date_select_trig" alt="" src="http://www.labwise.in/devel/skin/frontend/ultimo/default/images/xcalendar.gif.pagespeed.ic.nkzRZoIMTp.png">
  </div><div style="float:left;widht:50px">
                            <select name="date_time" id="date_time" class="input-select required-entry validate-select validation-failed" style="width: 50px;">
                                        <option value="">--</option>
                                        <option value="1">1</option>
                                        <option value="2">2</option>
                                        <option value="3">3</option>
                                        <option value="4">4</option>
                                        <option value="5">5</option>
                                        <option value="6">6</option>
                                        <option value="7">7</option>
                                        <option value="8">8</option>
                                        <option value="9">9</option>
                                        <option value="10">10</option>
                                        <option value="11">11</option>
                                        <option value="12">12</option>
                                </select><div style="" id="advice-required-entry-date_time" class="validation-advice">This is a required field.</div></div><div style="float:left">
                                <b>:</b>
  </div><div style="float:left">
                                <select name="date_time" id="date_time" class="input-select required-entry validate-select validation-failed" style="width: 50px;">
                                        <option value="">--</option>
                                        <option value="1">1</option>
                                        <option value="2">2</option>
                                        <option value="3">3</option>
                                        <option value="4">4</option>
                                        <option value="5">5</option>
                                        <option value="6">6</option>
                                        <option value="7">7</option>
                                        <option value="8">8</option>
                                        <option value="9">9</option>
                                        <option value="10">10</option>
                                        <option value="11">11</option>
                                        <option value="12">12</option>
                                </select>
  </div><div style="float:left">
                                <select name="date_time" id="date_time" class="input-select required-entry validate-select validation-failed" style="width: 50px;">
                                        <option value="">--</option>
                                        <option value="1">AM</option>
                                        <option value="2">PM</option>
                                </select>
  </div><div style="float:left">
                        </div></div>
```

Comment: it is getting more gap between the radio buttons

Comment: updated kind check the answer

Comment: it is showing same the gap is so much it is not getting as in the image also

Comment: I have added the image file after applying your code

Comment: it is css issue nothing with validation concern

Comment: Ok then how can I make it fine.It is looking awkward.

Comment: give me link i will check

Comment: updated answer kindly check and feedback

Comment: working but the the alert message is getting middle of the radio buttons

Comment: yes it is default i will show like that for every radio

Comment: Can't we make it is as the first image which is provided actually the requirement is that

Comment: check that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19333539/how-to-validate-radio-button-in-magento may be helpful in ur case

Comment: yes checked and tried but i can't understand we need to use for both the radio buttons or not??

Comment: @ Qaissar Satti It has worked can you please suggest for other field also "Test Schedule"

Comment: @Mouni  what you want on that field?

Comment: please review two images what i have posted it should be as in the first image

Comment: you want to add calender on that field?

Comment: I have added the calendar field also when click on submit the required field is showing as 2nd image it has to show as in the 1st image.

Comment: add  it like that `<div style="float:left">//input field here</div><div style="float:left">//image here</div><div style="float:left">//select drop down here</div>`

Comment: No it is not working it is showing same

Comment: give me link of url

Comment: update the answer copy paste html and see

Comment: No.Once check the link the (:) symbol is misplacing

Comment: i tested and it's working without any problem

Comment: add it in separate  div it will show perfectly

Comment: please once check my link it is not perfect.

Comment: I have added in this way <div style="float:left"><b>:</b></div> but it is not showing perfectly

Comment: kindly add the width on select box that match with error message

Comment: Ok.fine Can you please suggest me how to post these radio button values and test schedule in mail function

Comment: this is another question kindly post the another question

Comment: added as new question.Please review it and suggest me

Answer (score 2):

If you are using magento form validation add class(**magento-checkbox-validation**) in your **radio inputs**(of same group):

```
class="magento-checkbox-validation" OR use "validate-one-required" on the last radio/checkbox in the group
```

And if you are writing your custom script then add this function in script :

```
  function validateRadioIsSelected()
{
 var options = $$('input.Classname');
    for( i in options ) {
        if( options[i].checked == true ) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

if above function return true, it means your radio is selected

Answer (score 1):

You have to set class name in radio box input field

`class="validate-one-required-by-name".`

check for above value.

Comment: Where i need to put in my code.please suggest me.

Comment: As in the image i need to get the alert when i click on the submit button

Comment: For radio button validation,<input type="radio"  class="validate-one-required-by-name"  name="radiobutton" value="" />

Comment: that's was the doubt for both buttons should i need to add

Comment: you can check by adding in both button.if its not working then you can add that class into label tag class above li of radio.

Comment: it is showing only for one.But I want it to show as in the image

Comment: sorry. i am not understand your query.plz explain it again.

Comment: same as in the image it has to show but it is showing only for one radio button